# ElasticSearch document is getting updated even after IfSeqNo and IfPrimaryTerm values don't match with assigned sequence number and primary term

Tags: java, elasticsearch, optimistic-concurrency

I am attempting to verify whether an Elastic search document is being updated correctly by using an index request that has a different sequence number and primary term than what was assigned to the document. According to the documentation if IfSeqNo and IfPrimaryTerm values do not match with sequence_no and primary term of document then ES will throw VersionConflictEngineException . In my test code document is getting updated and sequence number is being incremented, even though I've set an old sequence number in my index request. I was expecting a VersionConflictEngineException exception to be thrown but this is not happening. Let me know what is wrong with my code. Thanks in advance.

Attaching my java code. test method is the entry point. I tried doing same thing from kibana client on same ES cluster but it is working as expected (throwing exception).

Elasticsearch version is 6.8
JavaClient version is elasticsearch-6.6.1

```java
 /**
     * only perform this indexing request if the document was last modification was assigned the given
     * sequence number. Must be used in combination with {@link #setIfPrimaryTerm(long)}
     *
     * If the document last modification was assigned a different sequence number a
     * {@link org.elasticsearch.index.engine.VersionConflictEngineException} will be thrown.
     */
    public IndexRequest setIfSeqNo(long seqNo) { }
```

Kibana client example

```
POST /table_index/_doc/606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3?if_seq_no=1574635&if_primary_term=6
{
    "name" : "test_table_6SjooYiji3",
    "description" : null,
    "catalogId" : "606635778254",
    "databaseName" : "db_dcs_int_test4"
}

Response from kibana

{
   "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
        "reason": "[gluetable][606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3]: version conflict, required seqNo [1574635], primary term [6]. current document has seqNo [1574661] and primary term [6]",
        "index_uuid": "jisjayWfTTe7Rd-Ll48qWw",
        "shard": "0",
        "index": "table_index"
      }
    ],
    "type": "version_conflict_engine_exception",
    "reason": "[gluetable][606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3]: version conflict, required seqNo [1574635], primary term [6]. current document has seqNo [1574661] and primary term [6]",
    "index_uuid": "jisjayWfTTe7Rd-Ll48qWw",
    "shard": "0",
    "index": "table_index"
   },
   "status": 409
}
```

```
private void test() {
    String catalogId="606635778254";
    String databaseName="db_dcs_int_test4";
    String tableName="test_table_6SjooYiji3";
    com.amazon.spektrdatacataloglambda.DBTable dbTable = new com.amazon.spektrdatacataloglambda.DBTable();
    dbTable.setName(tableName);
    dbTable.setCatalogId(catalogId);
    dbTable.setMetadata(new HashMap<String, String>(){{ put("test","singhjfi");}});
    elasticSearchUtils.upsertTableToTableIndexInES(catalogId, databaseName, dbTable, true, null);
}
    
    
public void upsertTableToTableIndexInES(final String catalogId, final String databaseName, final DBTable table,
                                        final Boolean isOverwriteESTableDoc,
                                        final GetResponse tableESDocument) {
    IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(ES_TABLE_INDEX, ES_TABLE_INDEX_DOC_TYPE);

    if (isOverwriteESTableDoc) {
        // doing to prevent any data loss because of multiple update call from other DCS clients
        // TODO: remove after testing
        indexRequest = indexRequest.setIfSeqNo(1574633);
        indexRequest = indexRequest.setIfPrimaryTerm(6);
        log.info("setting sequence number and primary term");
    }

    final Map<String, Object> payload = getMapFromObject(table);
    //Append table, database for search and actual payload information as string (no search on it).
    payload.put(ES_TABLE_INDEX_DATABASE_NAME_KEY, databaseName);
    payload.put(ES_DOC_KEY_CATALOG_ID, catalogId);

    final String tableName = table.getName();
    final String id = getESTableId(catalogId, databaseName, tableName);

    indexRequest.source(payload).id(id);

    log.info("Adding {} to elasticsearch index:{} as type {} with id {}", GSON.toJson(payload),
            ES_TABLE_INDEX, ES_TABLE_INDEX_DOC_TYPE, id);

    performIndexRequest(indexRequest);

    log.info("Added {} to elasticsearch index:{} as type {} with id {}", GSON.toJson(payload),
            ES_TABLE_INDEX, ES_TABLE_INDEX_DOC_TYPE, id);
}
    
protected void performIndexRequest (IndexRequest indexRequest) {
    try {
        log.info("seq_num={}, primary_term={}", indexRequest.ifSeqNo(), indexRequest.ifPrimaryTerm());
        log.info("Initiating Index Request {} from ElasticSearch", indexRequest);
        IndexResponse indexResponse = elasticSearchClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        log.info("Index response {}", indexResponse);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String ioError = String.format("I/O Error when performing index request %s on ElasticSearch.", indexRequest);
        log.error(ioError, e);
        throw new DataCatalogException(ioError + " " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

logs

```
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,736 [INFO] [] (main) Utils:44 Initializing AppConfig with args:--root=build--realm=us-east-1--domain=beta
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,742 [INFO] [] (main) AppConfigTree:1556 Using config root at build/brazil-config
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,743 [INFO] [] (main) AppConfigTree:1703 Found domain = beta
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,743 [INFO] [] (main) AppConfigTree:1704 Found realm = us-east-1
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,743 [INFO] [] (main) AppConfigTree:1743 Determined appname = SpektrDataCatalogLambda
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,743 [INFO] [] (main) AppConfigTree:1759 Determined appgroup = SpektrDataCatalogLambda
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,744 [INFO] [] (main) AppConfigTree:1952 Parsing config file: build/brazil-config/app/SpektrDataCatalogLambda.cfg
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,749 [INFO] [] (main) MixedCaseTableUtils:116 tempDirPrefix=/tmp/beta
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:46,794 [INFO] [] (main) Utils:70 creating DCS client for awsAccountId=606635778254, realm=us-east-1, dcsEndpoint=https://datacatalogv2.beta.spektr.a2z.com
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:50,746 [INFO] [] (main) Utils:57 Getting your credentials from Conduit.
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:52,650 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchClientFactory:46 Initialized ES URL as search-spektr-es-datacatalog-6-8-cq2riup3kroeai2hokcrfxh5me.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:52,909 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchUtils:121 setting sequence number and primary term
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:53,009 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchUtils:134 Adding {"name":"test_table_6SjooYiji3","catalogId":"606635778254","metadata":{"test":"singhjfi"},"retentionPeriodInDays":0,"databaseName":"db_dcs_int_test4"} to elasticsearch index:table_index as type gluetable with id 606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:53,010 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchEnabledGlueDataCatalog:1971 seq_num=1574633, primary_term=6
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:53,011 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchEnabledGlueDataCatalog:1972 Initiating Index Request index {[table_index][gluetable][606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3], source[{"name":"test_table_6SjooYiji3","description":null,"catalogId":"606635778254","owner":null,"partitionKeys":null,"storageDescriptor":null,"storageDetails":null,"parameters":null,"lastRefreshedTime":null,"encryptedData":null,"versioned":null,"versionColumns":null,"metadata":{"test":"singhjfi"},"retentionPeriodInDays":0,"retention":null,"autoApproveReadRequest":null,"databaseName":"db_dcs_int_test4"}]} from ElasticSearch
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:53,885 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchEnabledGlueDataCatalog:1974 Index response IndexResponse[index=table_index,type=gluetable,id=606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3,version=35,result=updated,seqNo=1574661,primaryTerm=6,shards={"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}]
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:53,885 [INFO] [] (main) ElasticSearchUtils:139 Added {"name":"test_table_6SjooYiji3","catalogId":"606635778254","metadata":{"test":"singhjfi"},"retentionPeriodInDays":0,"databaseName":"db_dcs_int_test4"} to elasticsearch index:table_index as type gluetable with id 606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3
[java] 11 Apr 2023 17:05:53,885 [INFO] [] (main) MixedCaseTableUtils:143 Done operation=test
```

Answer (score 0):

The big difference I see is that in Kibana you're using the `_doc` type whereas in your code the mapping type is `gluetable`, so you're not updating what you think you're updating.

In Kibana you're indexing

```
/table_index/_doc/606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3
```

whereas in your test code you're indexing

```
/table_index/gluetable/606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3
```

which are two different documents.

Make sure that `ES_TABLE_INDEX_DOC_TYPE = "_doc"` in your code and you should get the same error.

Comment: `gluetable` is type field in ES index request.

same is displayed in kibana output as well "reason": "[gluetable][606635778254_db_dcs_int_test4_test_table_6SjooYiji3]:

Comment: Can you share the mapping you get from `GET table_index` ?

Comment: `GET table_index` output https://sharetext.me/v7wmpipjpl

Comment: Your index mapping has a `gluetable` doc type, which have been [deprecated in ES 7.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/removal-of-types.html) (and removed in 8.x), where the `_doc` type is the only valid one. It would probably be  a good idea to reindex your index to remove the `gluetable` type which doesn't make sense anymore in ES 7.x

Comment: Thanks Val, will upgrade our ES server accordingly. 

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading the ES java client package from 6.6.1 to 7.9.3 it is throwing exception as expected.

Found hint from client source code

```
     if (out.getVersion().onOrAfter(Version.V_6_6_0)) {
            out.writeZLong(ifSeqNo);
            out.writeVLong(ifPrimaryTerm);
        } else if (ifSeqNo != UNASSIGNED_SEQ_NO || ifPrimaryTerm != UNASSIGNED_PRIMARY_TERM) {
            assert false : "setIfMatch [" + ifSeqNo + "], currentDocTem [" + ifPrimaryTerm + "]";
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                "sequence number based compare and write is not supported until all nodes are on version 7.0 or higher. " +
                    "Stream version [" + out.getVersion() + "]");
        }
```

Comment: You should not use a 7.9.3 client with a 6.8 server, it's really not a good idea.